# PHP - Display 2d array as table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i'm fairly new to PHP and I am having trouble with displaying a 2d array in a specific format.

Basically, I know how  print the 2d array normally, however it looks very messy and I've tried it with foreach but it doesn't give me the output that I want. I have a 2d array which I want to print out like a table of 5, so if there is 35 records in the array, I should print out 7 tables (each table prints 5 entries).

I tried using a forloop from 0 - 7 (for the tables) and inside the forloop I use a foreach to access the array elements, but when I did this, it basically printed everything from the array 7 times.

Comment: show an example of what you did and what you expect to happen

Comment: Are we suppose to guess a) what the array looks like b) what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Array
(
    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0115
            [1] => Nguyen
            [2] => Trang Luong Minh

        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0165
            [1] => Rana
            [2] => Shivam

The array is in this format, but I would like to show it like:

ID FIRST NAME LAST NAME
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]

ID FIRST NAME LAST NAME
[5]
[6]
etc...

where [i] is each cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $cars = array
        (
        array("Volvo", 22, 18),
        array("BMW", 15, 13),
        array("Saab", 5, 2),
        array("Land Rover", 17, 15),
        array("benz", 252, 1558),
        array("tesla", 115, 193),
        array("chevy", 587, 211),
        array("ford", 13217, 115),
        array("Volvo", 22, 18),
        array("BMW", 15, 13),
        array("Saab", 5, 2),
        array("Land Rover", 17, 15),
        array("benz", 252, 1558),
        array("tesla", 115, 193),
        array("chevy", 587, 211),
        array("ford", 13217, 115),
        array("Volvo", 22, 18),
        array("BMW", 15, 13),
        array("Saab", 5, 2),
        array("Land Rover", 17, 15),
        array("benz", 252, 1558),
        array("tesla", 115, 193),
        array("chevy", 587, 211),
        array("ford", 13217, 115),
        array("Volvo", 22, 18),
        array("BMW", 15, 13),
        array("Saab", 5, 2),
        array("Land Rover", 17, 15),
        array("benz", 252, 1558),
        array("tesla", 115, 193),
        array("chevy", 587, 211),
        array("ford", 13217, 115),
        array("tesla", 115, 193),
        array("chevy", 587, 211),
        array("ford", 13217, 115),
    );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($cars as $innerCar) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            echo "<table style='display:inline;'>";
            echo "<tbody>";
        }
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($innerCar as $car) {
            echo "<td>$car</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        if ($i == 5) {
            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
            $i = 0;
        } else {
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this magic??? thank you so much!! I'll be studying this code to see exactly how it worked, it looks like each foreach statement is using the first array as an index, and delving deeper into that array to use the next array as an index

Answer (score 0):

If i've understand what you're trying to do, this is a solution:

```
foreach ($array as $subArray){
    foreach($subArray as $element){
        print "$element";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't output the elements of the array, instead it just says" ARRAY ARRAY ARRAY ARRAY"

my array was constructed as such:
$data = array(); 
//read in data from text file
list($ID, $last, $first) = explode (",",$line);
$data = array($ID, $last, $first);
$parent[] = $data;

Comment: Edit the question to explain, i thought you had array of arrays

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the index of the array and a modulus calculation to work out where to split the array into a new table:

```
$people = [
    [0115, 'Nguyen', 'Trang Luong Minh'],
    [0165, 'Rana', 'Shivam'],
    [0165, 'Family1', 'Given1'],
    [0165, 'Family2', 'Given2'],
    [0165, 'Family3', 'Given3'],
    [0165, 'Family4', 'Given4'],
    [0165, 'Family5', 'Given5'],
    [0165, 'Family6', 'Given6'],
    [0165, 'Family7', 'Given7'],
    [0165, 'Family8', 'Given8'],
    [0165, 'Family9', 'Given9'],
    [0165, 'Family10', 'Given10'],
  ];

$items_per_table = 5;

foreach ($people as $index => $person) {
  $item_index = $index % $items_per_table;

  if ($item_index == 0) {
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Given Name</th><th>Family Name</th></tr>';  
  }

  echo '<tr>';
  foreach ($person as $data) {
    echo "<td>{$data}</td>";
  }
  echo '</tr>';

  if ($item_index == $items_per_table - 1 || count($people) == $index + 1) {
    echo '</table>';
  }
}
```